# How to match two tables with different primary key lengths

Tags: sql

I'm trying to reference two primary keys from two different tables, but the problem is that they don't match due to its character length.

For an example , `person.personid = '1234'` and `department.personid = '12345'`.

Is there an SQL statement in which I can use to match the first 4 or 5 characters of the primary keys or is there any other methods that I can use.

---

UPDATE : My sincere apologies. I am dealing with two tables. `"dyndomrun.ddid"` is with a Primary key and `"domainregion.domainid"` is without any primary key nor foreign key. "dyndomrun" table DDL is set to `"character varying"` and has 8 characters, whereas "domainregion" table DDL is also set to "character varying" but has 10 characters.

Problem : There are some fields in `domainregion` table that needs to be joined together with the primary key in `dyndomrun` table. I can't seem to do this with a simple SQL statement such as below

```
SELECT domainregion.domainid, dyndomrun.ddid 
FROM domainregion, dyndomrun 
WHERE domainregion.domainid = dyndomrun.ddid 
ORDER BY domainregion.domainid, dyndomrun.ddid;
```

I have tried JOINS, INNER JOINS, LIKE, none of them seems to work. The database that I am dealing with is purely SQL based stored using PostgreSQL.

Please advise.

Comment: What database engine? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Other?

Comment: I would create a mapping table with columns p_person_id and d_person_id

Comment: Typically, you don't match primary keys between tables - one table's **foreign key** references another table's **primary key** - and those two need to be identical in their data type

Comment: Why is your primary key a string? They should generally be numeric types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense.  We don't map the primary key of one table to the primary key of another table.

Now we do map the foreign key of a dependent table to the primary key of the referenced table.    But it that case the value of the column in both tables has to match.  `12345` in DEPARTMENT.PERSONID must refer to a record `12345` in PERSON.PERSONID, because `1234` in .PERSON.PERSONID is literally a different person.

Perhaps you're working with a whacky data model, in which the dependent table has some smart key only part of which refers to the parent key.  If that's the case, my condolences.  But you need to give some specific details, and some indication of flavour of DBMS (because solutions will vary across different products).

But your biggest problem is this: once you try to apply relational integrity on anything other than equality between columns you run the risk of matching `1234` in .PERSON.PERSONID with `1234` in DEPARTMENT.PERSONID, `12345` in DEPARTMENT.PERSONID *and* `123456` in DEPARTMENT.PERSONID.  That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like

```
select * 
  from t1
     , t2
 where to_char(t1.id) = substr(t2.id,1,4)
```

Or other way:

```
select * 
  from t1
     , t2
 where t1.id = round(t2.id/10)
```

Both above solutions assumes that `t1.id` is one char shorter than `t2.id`.

HTH

Comment: My problem is that I need to select a list of fields from a specific table and they are also called in another table as a primary key, just with different set of characters in the primary key. The Primary key type is "character varying", therefore it states this error "No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.".

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM person
 INNER JOIN department ON person.personid = LEFT(department.personid,4)
```